# Elementtree displaying elements out of order

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using Python's ElementTree to parse xml files. I have a "findall" to find all "revision" subelements, but when I iterate through the result, they are not in document order. What can I be doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
allrevisions = page.findall('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.5/}revision')
for rev in allrevisions:
    print rev
    print rev.find('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.5/}timestamp').text
```

Here's a link to the document I'm parsing: http://pastie.org/2780983

Thanks,
 bsg

-Oops. By going through my code and running it piece by piece, I worked out the problem - I had stuck in a reverse() on the elements list in the wrong place, which was causing all the trouble. Thank you so much for your help - I'm sorry it was such a silly issue.

Comment: Could we have a link to a sample document?

Comment: The document I'm parsing is exported from Wikipedia. (The Mind of a Leader). How can I post a link to that?

Comment: Just paste it somewhere online. http://pastie.org for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) says that `findall` returns the elements in document order.

A quick test shows the correct behaviour:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xmltext = """
<root>
    <number>1</number>
    <number>2</number>
    <number>3</number>
    <number>4</number>
</root>
"""

tree = et.fromstring(xmltext)

for number in tree.findall('number'):
    print number.text
```

**Result:**

```
1
2
3
4
```

It would be helpful to see the document you are parsing.

---

**Update:**

Using the source data you provided:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

with open('xmldata.xml', 'r') as f:
    xmldata = f.read()

tree = et.fromstring(xmldata)

for revision in tree.findall('.//{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.5/}revision'):
    print revision.find('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.5/}text').text[0:10].encode('utf8')
```

**Result:**

```
‘The Mind 
{{db-spam}
‘The Mind 
'''The Min
<!-- Pleas
```

The same order as they appear in the document.

Comment: That is incredibly weird - mine comes out as:                           'The Mind  '''The Mind  'The Mind  {{db-spam <!-- Pleas  - completely out of order. Can the fact that I'm using elementtree.parse to read in the file rather than fromstring have anything to do with it?

Comment: Using parse doesn't change my output.. I'm stumped.

Comment: Very strange - I cut out all the extraneous code in my program and got the results in the right order. I must be messing it up somewhere in the middle. Thanks a lot for your help!